# Combine several similar rows into one with new columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Original table:

```
Name         Age      Contact_type   Contact
Alex         20       SMS            12345
Alex         20       Email          abc@gmail.com
Alex         20       SMS            54321
Bob          35       SMS            23456
```

I want to make it as:

```
Name          Age     Contact_type1   Contact_1  Contact_type2  Contact_2       Contact_type3 Contact_3
Alex          20           SMS          12345        Email     abc@gmail.com        SMS          23456
Bob           35           SMS          23456
```

If name and age are duplicated, combine the 2(or more) rows into 1 row with new column as shown above.

I want to do that by finding the same 'Name' and 'Age', and using DISTINCT CONTACT like case when count distinct(contact)>0 but it seems so many syntax error occur. Is there any smarter method to make it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial pivot, because you need to generate a sequential number for the pivoting.  The code looks like:

```
select name,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then contact_type end) as contacttype1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then contact end) as contact1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then contact_type end) as contacttype2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then contact end) as contact2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then contact_type end) as contacttype3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then contact end) as contact3
from (select ot.*,
             (@rn := if(@n = name, @rn + 1,
                        if(@n := name, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from originaltable ot cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @n := '') params
      order by name
     ) ot
group by name;
```

Note:  this assumes you know the maximum number of contacts.  If you don't, you either need to use dynamic SQL or put them into one column using `group_concat()` and funky separators.